# Angular: change data on ng-repeat with filter function

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to change object's attribute's values on a `ng-repeat` loop using a filter function?

My project is a shopping cart that list products depending on the view and I have an argument 'discount' which will cut 50% off the price of the product and I wish to apply the change using a filter on the `ng-repeat`.

My data structure is :

```
[{  
    "categorie": "",
    "name": "",   
    "price": 12
}]
```

My `ng-repeat` loop looks like:

```
ng-repeat product in products |filter:'priceFilter()
```

and my function defined inside the controller is:

```
var priceFilter = function(product){
    var filtered = [];
    if (discount == true) {
        for (var i = 0; i< product.length; i++) {
            product.price = prix.price /2;
            filtered.push(product);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

What am I missing? Right now it filters out all the results, sending back nothing.

Comment: also you don't need () on filter:priceFilter, also filter run on each items, so you don't have to make new array there, but check the item and return true. But filters are to filter out array item, not to modify them.

Comment: prix.price was product.price. Forgot to rewrite this part for display. And i thought about using a filter since the filter definitions says that it is creating a new array with valid results depending on the filter condition to check. So i tought it could modify data inside that looping array... My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products"> 
     <div> 
          {{applyDiscount(product.Price}} 
      </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$scope.applyDiscount= function(price){
        if ($scope.discount)
        {
            return price /2;
        }
        return price;}
```

As Camusensei said, the `applyDiscount` function will be run on every digest cycle, slowing the application down.
For performance issues, a better implementation would use a filter which is only run if the input changes.

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products"> 
     <div> 
          {{product.price | priceFilter:discount}}
      </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
myApp.filter("applyDiscount", function() {
  return function(price, discount) {
    if (discount)
        {
            return price /2;
        }
        return price;
  };
});
```

Comment: looks nice & easy trying it now :)

Comment: I have to say that this is extremely inefficient. The `applyDiscount` function will be run on every digest cycle, slowing the application down. A filter function is only run if the input changes.

Comment: So you should consider using a custom filter for dividing/multiplying the price in the case of a discount even if you want to go this path. syntax would be `{{product.price|applyDiscount:discount}}` or just `{{product.price|applyDiscount}}` using a global variable (less clean)

Comment: I added this information in the answer (with code example)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right way of [using a custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters)
As shown in that example, you need to add this line to your code:

```
angular.module("yourmodulename").filter('priceFilter', function() { return priceFilter; });
```

And you also need to change your html to:

```
<ng-repeat="product in products | priceFilter">
```

Answer (score 0):

filter is not what you want for this scenario, a custom filter should be used to determine whether something is valid or invalid. and should only return a true or false. All a filter is going to do is look at the current object in the list and determine whether it meets certain criteria to show in the list or not.

you should just change your html.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
<div ng-if="discount">
{{product.Price / 2}}
</div>
<div ng-if="!discount">
{{product.Price}}
</div>
</div>
```

edit:

if you want to change your data then your don't want to use a filter. you need to figure out before you loop what the data should show. if your discount is a simple checkbox you can add an `ng-change="adjustprice()"` to the checkbox and have adjustprice() do the manipulation. you don't want to touch ng-repeat data inside the ng-repeat. angular doesn't like this and will break stuff if you attempt it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As i read the doc for filters it says that it creates a new array pushing the filtered values inside. So i though this new array could do some more work on the fly... But i guess you of course right, must be better ways to do that ;)

Comment: This is a nice solution, however, you should not use `ng-if` but `ng-show` instead to avoid creating `2*product.length` useless child scopes